# flatMap requires result type

Tags: typescript

```js
type ApiItem = Record<string, unknown>;
type CSVItem = Record<string, unknown>;
type Model = { converter: (item: ApiItem) => CSVItem | CSVItem[] };

function convertItems(model: Model, { main }: { main: ApiItem[] }): CSVItem[] {
    const { converter } = model;

    return main.flatMap((item) => converter(item));
}
```

The `flatMap` instruction raises an error:

```
Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'CSVItem[]'.
  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'CSVItem'.
```

It works if I change the last line with:

```js
  return main.flatMap<CSVItem>((item) => converter(item));
```

I don't understand since the callback I give to `flatMap` is known and it returns a CSVItem or a CSVItem array, inference should work, I shouldn't have to specify the return type of the flatMap call.

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAgmCWBJYEC2UC8UBKEDGA9gE4AmAPAM7BHwB2A5gDRQCutA1rQQO60B8AbgBQoSFADCAZQBqyNJhz5i5KjQbM2nHv2GjoAWQIkIAGwUBvKIVoA3CERREAXFAAU8FKhdwkngJSYfBIycugAPsGyngDaALpQAL7CQgBmbHjA8AS0Vtl2DqEUrqhGpi6GxibMlqgAhnSJLjX1tN4IoXGJfi5SUWid5kJQw7m0VFCW1vmOiQollckjUEQQwCxEOXV0AHQpJrXA+rVgru7+gaPT9mdofn7CCUJAA)

Comment: I fail to fix it, it always gives me a broken thing :-(

Comment: It also works if you change CSVItem to something else: https://tsplay.dev/N9jD9m

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out myself how to get ride of the error properly:

```js
type Model = { converter: (item: ApiItem) => CSVItem | ReadonlyArray<CSVItem> }
```

flatMap seems to be able to infer U only if my `converter` functions returns a `ReadonlyArray` and not a usual array.

I don't really understand why though, but my typescript level is still warming slowly.

Comment: ... because of the `unknown` you put there instead of `any`. unknown types cannot be assigned to anything else, nor can you create methods on them. Unless there is very specific reason to add unknown type, you should add it.

Comment: The problem is caused by using the record type with unknown values ([example](https://tsplay.dev/mMX9rN)). For better or worse, a mutable array is assignable to a readonly array.

Comment: if I change CSVItem to `type CSVItem = Record<string, any>` the error is gone, but it says that `flatMap` returns `any[]` instead of `CSVItem[]`. That does not seem like the right solution. What am I missing here?